# Overflow dots not changing colour on pre-lollipop devices

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-theme

For some reason, when I use my theme below my overflow dots change colour on Lollipop devices but not on pre-Lollipop ones. Does anyone know why and how I can fix this issue?

```
<style name="NavyOverflow.Theme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/NavyOverflow.Theme.OverflowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="NavyOverflow.Theme.OverflowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_overflow_darkblue</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/NavyOverflow.Theme.OverflowStyle</item>
```

instead of

```
<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/NavyOverflow.Theme.OverflowStyle</item>
```

Almost all attributes used with appcompat-v7 themes should be without the `android` prefix.